# In DataForm , I want to override a variable in a release configuration, but do not work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform

I want to override the value of a variable set by var in dataform.json with a compiled variable in the release configuration, but it doesn't work as expected.

dataform.json

```
  "vars": {
      "some_variable": "0"  
  }
```

In the release configuration, I type "some_variable" as a key and am trying to override the value in dataform.json

[Release configuration setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TtfQ.png)

How should I write this?

Comment: Overrides won't show in the code itself. But will override in the release configuration. Once you compile the release configuration and execute it via a tag or similar, it will use the override. Does that explanation help?

Comment: Is this possibly a typing issue where the `1` in the GUI is interpreted as a string?  I have successfully [overridden variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77403118/6832816) but they were strings.