# dataform schema suffix for sources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform, google-dataform

I am trying to manage production and development environments using the GCP cloud GUI from the same code base.  I have created separate release configurations and workflow configurations based off of the same DAG, with the only difference that the production environment data resides in a schema with `_prod` as the suffix.

I have accordingly included the correct suffix in the release configuration for production:

[image]

However, I have discovered that it does not apply to my source data, which uses `schema: dataform.projectConfig.defaultSchema` in the declaration.  Am I configuring the project/release/workflows correctly?

Comment: Hi @KT12, Can you check this [Documentation1](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/reference/dataform-core-reference#iprojectconfig) and [Documentation2](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/configure-dataform) for configuring your project. might this will help you ?

Comment: My configuration is correct, it seems that you have to add custom logic to override the source schema suffix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was pretty simple:

Update the source declaration so that the schema is a concatenation of two variables:

`schema: dataform.projectConfig.defaultSchema + dataform.projectConfig.vars.source_suffix`

Add the following variable to the `dataform.json`

```
  "vars" : {
    "source_suffix" : ""
  }
```

For production releases, specify the variable override `source_suffix` to be `_prod`.